# Background gradients not working with Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Background gradients are not working with Bootstrap 3.0 `navbar-fixed-top` or `bottom`, just default.

```css
html, body
{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body
{
    background: #000000; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, #000000 , #434343); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, #000000 , #434343); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--  Navigation  -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

According to the DOM, I get an "*invalid property Value*" error. This only happens when I use the class `navbar-fixed-bottom`, or `navbar-fixed-top`.

Has anyone run into a similar issue or know what could be causing the page to appear white?

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/Xociety/pen/jAgoWR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason why this happens is because you are giving body the

`height: auto;`

this means that the height of the body will be calculated by the browser. but when you add `navbar-fixed-bottom` you add the fixed position to so the navbar height won't affect the body height and the browser calculates it as 0 height and the gradient is not shown.

if you change

`height: auto;`

to

`height: 100%;`

you tell the browser that you want the height 100% of the html. and the gradient will show since the body will show.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your `<html>` and `<body>` a height of `100%`.

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/PzrvGB)**

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be:

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom, .navbar-fixed-top
{
    position: inherit;
}
```